# how to turn a sorted list into tab delimited values in Python?

Tags: python

I have a sorted list that looks like this [('100','abc'),('99','bca')]. I want to turn this into something like this into a text file.

```
abc     100<br>
bca     99
```

I have tried this

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
writer.writerows(d)
```

but this gives me the output as:

```
100 abc<br>
99  bca
```

Comment: This is very basic Python, I suggest you read a tutorial and/or the Python documentation on Python [Lists](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html) and [Tuples](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/tuples.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the `csv` module unless your values have tabs in them and thus need quoting.

Look up the `with` statement to make sure your file gets closed when you're done with it and not a lot later, and the `format` method for the built-in string type.

```
source = [('100','abc'),('99','bca')]

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in source:
        f.write('{1}\t{0}\n'.format(*line));
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this one as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), this is pretty straight-forward:

```
import csv

data = [('100','abc'),('99','bca')]

# Use 'w' for other OS's than Windows
with open('my_data.csv', 'wb') as ofile: 
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(list(reversed(row)))
```

**`my_data.csv`:**

```
abc 100
bca 99
```